# PHP set timezone id using datefmt_set_timezone

Tags: php, timezone, intl

I've come across a deprecated statement in a piece of code;

```
$this->_dateTimeZone = new \DateTimeZone($timezone);
$this->_dateFormatter->setTimeZoneId($timezone);

Gives
Deprecated: IntlDateFormatter::setTimeZoneId(): Use datefmt_set_timezone() instead, which also accepts a plain time zone identifier and for which this function is now an alias
```

I thought, OK, I'll just switch to the suggested way of setting the time-zone so I tried:

```
$this->_dateTimeZone = new \DateTimeZone($timezone);
datefmt_set_timezone($timezone);

Gives
Warning: datefmt_set_timezone() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ...
```

I tried searching the manual for this function [here](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=datefmt_set_timezone&lang=en&scope=404quickref) but the function is not listed anywhere.

My question is; what 2 parameters are required? I can't seem to find anything related to the given function - though it clearly exists in the later versions of PHP.

Comment: How about this one? http://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.settimezone.php

Comment: @ToBe; Seems to be working. Strange that the suggested function does not exist in the manual though.

Comment: Probably something very new. It's listed as a procedural synonym on that page, but not it's mystical second parameter.